# How to fix this variable undefined error in pi value when math.h is used?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include, syntax-error, math.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 
#include <math.h>

void Multiply2Nos (float x, float y) {
    float result = x * y;
    printf("%.3f X %.3f = %.2f\n",x,y,result);
}
int main () {
    Multiply2Nos(3.8,5.3);
    Multiply2Nos(M_PI,2);
    return 0;
}
```

`identifier "M_PI" is undefined`

Anyone knows why this happens?
It compiles fine (gcc cygwin) but this error keeps coming up while showing error sqiggles in vs code.
Im sure the include path is correct.

I tried checking if the include path is coorect (it is).
The problem is with vs code it dosnt recognize variables defined in math.h how do i fix this?.This issue exists in other test editors as well idk why.
I tried the same code in an ide called "codelite" and it too showed the same error but compiled fine.

Comment: `M_PI` is a non-standard extension, that's why. The linked duplicate shows various ways to declare it yourself.

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: it compile fine

Comment: i use cygwin gcc 11.4.0

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nG5Ksgl